# Compare and get the Index from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an array, which is a collection of arrays.
say
( 
( 1, x, y, a), 
( 2, m, n, o),
( 3, s, t, u, v, w)
)

If I want to get the index of m, how do I get it?

Can that be done using  **NSMutableArray contains:(id)** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSArray *arrWithArr;
NSArray *arrWithM;
NSInteger arrIndex;
for (int i = 0; i< [arrWithArr count]; i++) {
    if ([[arrWithArr objectAtIndex:i] containsObject:@"m"]) {
        arrIndex = i; break;
    }
}
NSInteger mIndex = [[arrWithArr objectAtIndex:arrIndex]indexOfObject:@"m"];
```

Comment: Perfect, could get the array index and the element index. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check with this code:

```
int arrayPos = 0;
for (NSArray *tempArray in collectionArray)
{
  if(tempArray containsObject:@"m")
  {
     int indexOfWord = [tempArray indexOfObject:@"m"];
     NSlog(@"Array pos: %d Index is : %d",pos, indexOfWord);
  }
  pos++;
}
```

In the for loop you get each array that is added in the collection array. After that you are checking the existence of the word in the array. If it is present you are displaying it.
Also printing the position of array also.

The element is situated at:

```
NSString *str = [[collectionArrayObjectAtIndex:pos] objectAtIndex:indexOfWord];
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you're talking about, "`[NSMutableArray contains:]`" will tell you if object "B" exists in an array of {A, B, C}.

What you really need to do is come up a second function that does a fast enumeration through your parent array and then does the "`contains`" thing on the sub-arrays.  If it finds "m", return "YES" and the index of that entry in the parent array.

Comment: Yes, I was writing indeed in that way and I got the below ans.
Thanks indeed.